# Ruby/Win32API - How to pass structs using Array#pack

Tags: ruby, winapi

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

**Set console cursor position**

```
require 'Win32API'

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
GetStdHandle = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'GetStdHandle', 'L', 'L')
HConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle.call(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
SetConsoleCursorPosition = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'SetConsoleCursorPosition', ['L', 'P'], 'L')

x = 5
y = 2
buffer = [x, y].pack('ss')
p SetConsoleCursorPosition.call(HConsoleOutput, buffer) #=> 0 - FAIL
```

What i'm doing bad? maybe exists someway to transform `buffer` into a pointer to solve it? but `buffer` is a string, which means that it is already a pointer.

This work for me, using another function:

**Hide console cursor**

```
require 'Win32API'

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
GetStdHandle = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'GetStdHandle', 'L', 'L')
HConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle.call(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
SetConsoleCursorInfo = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'SetConsoleCursorInfo', ['L', 'P'], 'L')

cursor_size = 20
cursor_visible = 0
buffer = [cursor_size, cursor_visible].pack('LC')
# Hide console cursor.
p SetConsoleCursorInfo.call(HConsoleOutput, buffer) #=> 1 - SUCCESSFUL
```

Thanks for read!

Comment: [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) takes a `DWORD` value as its second parameter. It stores the x/y coordinates in the low and high word, respectively. This is passed by value, not as a pointer.

Comment: I'm trying with this: `buffer = (x << 16) | y` and `['L', 'P']` => `['L', 'L']` in `SetConsoleCursorInfo` but doesn't work, do you have any idea? thanks for answering.